# Как мне сделать такой 2,5d фон?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, svg

2,5d фон на странице как можно сделать такой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему бы не просто поставить эту картинку на фон?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант на SVG. *Ждём экспертную комиссию)*

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;} body {height: 100vh; width: 100vw; overflow: hidden;}
svg {height: 100vh; width: 100vw; background: #333;} rect {stroke: none;}
#l {fill: #999;} #r {fill: #555;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100vh" width="100%">
<defs>
<pattern id="box" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="575" width="300" patternTransform="scale(1)">
<rect height="200" width="150" transform="skewY(30)" id="l" />
<rect y="175" x="150" height="200" width="150" transform="skewY(-30)" id="r" />
<use xlink:href="#l" transform="translate(150, 285)" />
<use xlink:href="#r" transform="translate(-150, 285)" />
</pattern>
</defs>
<rect height="100vh" width="100%" fill="url(#box)" />
</svg>
```

> *ну что бы писать не тегом svg а присвоить как background: url и т д* –
>   MaximLensky

```html
<img src="https://svgshare.com/i/JLK.svg" style="height: 100vh; width: 100%;">
```

Comment: ссылку - откуда скомуниздил покажи

Comment: если преобразуешь в url то будет круто

Comment: ну что бы писать не тегом svg а присвоить как background: url и т д

Comment: Я сделал вариант на svg. Посмотри

Answer (score 6):

Источник: https://leaverou.github.io/css3patterns/

```css
body {
  background-color: #62bbd3;
  background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, #80c9dd 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #80c9dd 87.5%, #80c9dd), linear-gradient(150deg, #80c9dd 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #80c9dd 87.5%, #80c9dd), linear-gradient(30deg, #80c9dd 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #80c9dd 87.5%, #80c9dd), linear-gradient(150deg, #80c9dd 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #80c9dd 87.5%, #80c9dd), linear-gradient(60deg, #d5eaf0 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #d5eaf0 75%, #d5eaf0), linear-gradient(60deg, #d5eaf0 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #d5eaf0 75%, #d5eaf0);
  background-size: 40px 70px;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 20px 35px, 20px 35px, 0 0, 20px 35px;
}
```

Второй пример

```css
body {
  background: #556;
  background-size: 80px 140px;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 40px 70px, 40px 70px, 0 0, 40px 70px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445), -webkit-linear-gradient(-60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445), -webkit-linear-gradient(60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445), -webkit-linear-gradient(-60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445), -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, #99a 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #99a 75%, #99a), -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, #99a 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #99a 75%, #99a);
}
```

Третий вариант svg

```css
body{
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 100 120' width='100'%3E%3Crect width='100%25' height='100%25'/%3E%3Cpath d='M0,30 50,0 100,30 50,60z' fill='%23333333'/%3E%3Cpath d='M0,30 50,60 50,120 0,90' fill='%23555555'/%3E%3Cpath d='M50,60 100,30 100,90 50,120' fill='%23999999'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

Comment: Мощно ) Сила css.