# Создать паттерн из "кубов"

Tags: html, вёрстка, svg

Есть растровый паттерн:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно создать подобный паттерн  в svg?

Не совсем понятно как можно провести половину каждой второй диагонали шестиугольника.

Из наработок есть:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" width="20%" height="20%">
      <polygon points="569.2,518 396,618 222.8,518 222.8,318 396,218 569.2,318" fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="2%" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  
  <circle cx="200"  cy="200" r="100" stroke="black" fill="url('#pattern')" />
</svg>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1098115/308951

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Рисуется несколько path заготовка для pattern

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 15 15">

<g fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="0.5">
<path  class="left-shade" d="M0 0l5 3v5l-5 -3z"></path> 
   <path fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="0.5"  class="right-shade" d="M10 0l-5 3v5l5 -3"></path> 
     
 </g> 
</svg>
```

- Затем они клонируются и смещаются

```
  <use x="5" y="8" xlink:href="#hex"></use>
     <use x="-5" y="8" xlink:href="#hex"></use>
```

Всё это происходит внутри pattern

- Затем можно применять паттерн к окружности :

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
   
   <pattern id="pattern-hexs" x="0" y="126" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="126" height="200" viewBox="0 0 10 16"> 
         <g id="hex" fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="0.5">
           <path  class="left-shade" d="M0 0l5 3v5l-5 -3z"></path>
       <path   class="right-shade" d="M10 0l-5 3v5l5 -3"></path>
     </g>
    
         <use x="5" y="8" xlink:href="#hex"></use>
     <use x="-5" y="8" xlink:href="#hex"></use>
   
   </pattern>
      
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="url(#pattern-hexs)" stroke="crimson" />
</svg>
```

- Или, например к прямоугольнику

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
   
   <pattern id="pattern-hexs" x="0" y="126" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="126" height="200" viewBox="0 0 10 16"> 
         <g id="hex" fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="0.5">
           <path  class="left-shade" d="M0 0l5 3v5l-5 -3z"></path>
       <path   class="right-shade" d="M10 0l-5 3v5l5 -3"></path>
     </g>
    
         <use x="5" y="8" xlink:href="#hex"></use>
     <use x="-5" y="8" xlink:href="#hex"></use>
      </pattern>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-hexs)"></rect>
  </svg>
```

Comment: На месте стыков видны явные артефакты несостыковки

Answer (score 2):

Комментарий @Voprositel

> На месте стыков видны явные артефакты несостыковки

Благодарю **@Sevastopol** за уточнение в комментарии, добавить закрывающий символ `z`
Это уменьшает артефакты несостыковки  линий за счет утолщения (две линии рядом)

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
   
   <pattern id="pattern-hexs" x="0" y="126" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="126" height="200" viewBox="0 0 10 16"> 
         <g id="hex"  stroke="orange" stroke-width="0.5">
           <path  fill="none" class="left-shade" d="M0 0l5 3v5l-5 -3z"></path>
       <path fill="none"  class="right-shade" d="M10 0l-5 3v5l5 -3z"></path>
     </g>
    
         <use x="5" y="8" xlink:href="#hex"></use>
     <use x="-5" y="8" xlink:href="#hex"></use>
   
   </pattern>
      
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="url(#pattern-hexs)" stroke="crimson" />
</svg>
```

Но необходимо найти решение, чтобы эти две соседние линии наложились друг на друга.

Эти вертикальные линии находятся в соседних ячейках `pattern` поэтому решение будет уменьшить ширину паттерна, чтобы вертикальные линии наложились друг на друга, оставив в итоге ширину одной линии.

Было:
`<pattern id="pattern-hexs" x="0" y="126" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="126" height="200" viewBox="0 0 10 16">`

Стало: `<pattern id="pattern-hexs" x="0" y="124" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="124" height="200" viewBox="0 0 10 16">`

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
   
   <pattern id="pattern-hexs" x="0" y="124" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="124" height="200" viewBox="0 0 10 16"> 
         <g id="hex"  stroke="orange" stroke-width="0.5">
           <path  fill="none" class="left-shade" d="M0 0l5 3v5l-5 -3z"></path>
       <path fill="none"  class="right-shade" d="M10 0l-5 3v5l5 -3z"></path>
     </g>
    
         <use x="5" y="8" xlink:href="#hex"></use>
     <use x="-5" y="8" xlink:href="#hex"></use>
   
   </pattern>
      
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="url(#pattern-hexs)" stroke="crimson" />
</svg>
```

*Вариант с закраской правой грани кубика*

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
   
   <pattern id="pattern-hexs" x="0" y="124" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="124" height="200" viewBox="0 0 10 16"> 
         <g id="hex"  stroke="grey"  stroke-width="0.25">
           <path  fill="none" class="left-shade" d="M0 0l5 3v5l-5 -3z"></path>
       <path fill="grey"  class="right-shade" d="M10 0l-5 3v5l5 -3z"></path>
     </g>
    
         <use x="5" y="8" xlink:href="#hex"></use>
     <use x="-5" y="8" xlink:href="#hex"></use>
   
   </pattern>
      
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="url(#pattern-hexs)" stroke="grey" />
</svg>
```

*Вариант с закраской левой грани*

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
   
   <pattern id="pattern-hexs" x="0" y="124" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="124" height="200" viewBox="0 0 10 16"> 
         <g id="hex"  stroke="grey"  stroke-width="0.25">
           <path  fill="grey" class="left-shade" d="M0 0l5 3v5l-5 -3z"></path>
       <path fill="none"  class="right-shade" d="M10 0l-5 3v5l5 -3z"></path>
     </g>
    
         <use x="5" y="8" xlink:href="#hex"></use>
     <use x="-5" y="8" xlink:href="#hex"></use>
   
   </pattern>
      
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="url(#pattern-hexs)" stroke="grey" />
</svg>
```